# Next.js | Can't return value from promise object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

**Hey there.**

I'm relatively new to JS and React, so please be kind with me. Trying to figure this out for quite some time.

I have a component parsing a JSON from a URL, then trying to return a value from it, so this can be rendered to the HTML body.

```js
import GetQuote from './quoteparse/GetQuote';
import * as bodystyles from './styles/dumbbody';

export default function Dumbbody() {

    return (
        <>
            <bodystyles.quote>
                <GetQuote />
            </bodystyles.quote>       
        </>
    )
}
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const GetQuote = async() => {

    const [newQuote, setNewQuote] = useState('');
    
    const randomQuoteURI = "https://www.tronalddump.io/random/quote";
    const response = await fetch(randomQuoteURI);
    const data = await response.json()
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result.value);
            setNewQuote(result.value);
        })
    console.log(newQuote);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                {`${newQuote}`}
            </p>
        </div>
    )

}

export default GetQuote;
```

I'm getting the error below:

[image]

Comment: The second part of the answer from the question Jared linked to should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you have is because your GetQuote is an async/await function which will return a Promise instead of JSX (the object representation of HTML for React to know to render). For this to work, you can put your fetch statement into a function and use useEffect to run the function when the component is rendered like below:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const GetQuote = async() => {
  const [newQuote, setNewQuote] = useState('');
  const randomQuoteURI = "https://www.tronalddump.io/random/quote";
  const getQuote = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(randomQuoteURI)
    const data = await response.json()
    setNewQuote(data)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getQuote()
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {`${newQuote}`}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
export default GetQuote;
```

You can read more about how React render the component [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), more about JSX [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html), more about how React Component's life-cycle [here](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/), how async/await works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and how to use async/await with React [here](https://dev.to/vinodchauhan7/react-hooks-with-async-await-1n9g)

Answer (score 0):

You're using Next.js, so I think you can also use `getInitialProps` provide by next.js for data fetching, you can see [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) for more info!

```
const GetQuote = ({ quote }) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {`${quote}`}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}

GetQuote.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const randomQuoteURI = "https://www.tronalddump.io/random/quote";
  const response = await fetch(randomQuoteURI);
  const response = await response.json()
  return { quote: response.value }
}
```